# Scala functional programming: Should I use 'throw' or 'throw new'?

Tags: scala

Doing some functional programming in Scala, and coming from a Java background, I tend to throw my exceptions like this:

```
throw new MyException("something is wrong")
```

However, I've also seen people omit `new`:

```
throw MyException("something is wrong")
```

Which is the more idiomatic way?

Comment: It doesn't matter. If you're trying to follow best function programming/Scala practices, you should be striving to not throw exceptions, anyway.

Comment: If the Exception class is an object, then you may omit it. Otherwise, you're calling the class

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd say the idiomatic way is to avoid exceptions altogether and use [`Either`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/rc2/scala/Either.html) instead. Scala is a functional language. Functions should return values, not have side effects. Exceptions are side effects. `Either` gives you the means to define a happy path and a sad path, separately.

Comment: What about `Try` and `Success`?

Comment: @cricket_007 Sure, what about suggesting that in an answer of your own :-)

Comment: Nah, I think `Either` is more broadly used without more context to the problem

Comment: In 2.11, Try is properly right-biased and has functionality that supports useful semantics. With the changes to Either in 2.12, I'd use that instead as it now has decent support for the more general usage.